# Blazor not correctly redirecting to controller on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have started on a blazor-webassembly PWA project (.net 5.0-rc1), hosted on asp.net core, and is working Authentication against 3rd party services.
This login flow is based on asp.net core identity.
The flow is as follows:

- User enters login site and chooses a provider
- User is redirected to controller, loading provider configuration and redirects user to provider
- User log in using provider
- User is redirected to callback, and is logged into system, JWT is generated
- User is redirected to PWA for handling of JWT.

When developing locally, the above flow works without any issues.
However when deploying to my webhotel, step 2 is redirected to the Blazor application, rather than the controller on the server, causing a "Not found" page.

As the server is hosting the application they share the same base url.
I have tried both a regular link <a href="..."> and navigate with Navigationmanager.NagivateTo(url, forLoad: true);

When shown the "Not Found" page, pressing F5 will result in the same page. However pressing Ctrl+F5 causes the server endpoint to be hit, and the rest of the flow works as intented.

Comment: On the page where you press Ctrl+F5, what does the Url in the address bar look like at that moment?

Comment: did you host the site as an application in iis? could you share the sample link code? you could try to use the failed request tracing ti check the 404 error detail. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: @HenkHolterman The URL looks exactly as I would expect it to when targeting the server. Can compare the URL on the [Site](https://masterplaner.m-mano.dk/) and compare it with the endpoints exposed by [Swagger](https://masterplaner.m-mano.dk/swagger/).

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Unfortunately I am unable to access the IIS of the host. Links can be found in earlier comment.

Comment: @MartinManø Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @LoulG. Unfortunately no. I have started thinking in other ways to handle authorization (eg. having my IDP on another subdomain). If I still have issues, I'll have to look for some other hosting. My most recent test were performed after updating to the release version of .net5.0

Comment: This answer solved a similar problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62088093

Comment: @laudable-logic This solved it for me. Thank you for the link. The original question have been updated to refer to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue were the serviceworker, catching all requests and sending them to index.html. The answer to this issue can be found in the following: [URL Rewrite exceptions for Blazor WebAssembly Hosted deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62073764/url-rewrite-exceptions-for-blazor-webassembly-hosted-deployment/62088093#62088093)